# How do I use Common Lisp CFFI to close all windows of an Gtk4 app?

Tags: common-lisp, gtk4, cffi

It appears that the way to close a Gtk4 library is by closing all the windows. The gir based bindings only allow the closing of a single window.

https://docs.gtk.org/glib/type_func.List.foreach.html seems to be the way to go.

I want to pass to it the list of application windows and call the window-close function.
Please critique my very naive attempt.
Assuming my gtk4 functions are correct, how do I do the following in cffi?

```
 (cffi:define-foreign-library libglib)
 (cffi:use-foreign-library libglib)
 (cffi:defcfun "g_list_foreach" :void
   (list :pointer)
   (func :pointer)
   (user-data :pointer))
 (cffi:foreign-funcall "g_list_foreach"
                       :pointer (gtk4:application-windows app)
                       :pointer #'gtk4:window-close
                       :pointer nil)
```

I built my app using https://github.com/bohonghuang/cl-gtk4 and added glib bindings to my fork. However, git introspection does not provide the way to do what I need.

## possible solution

```
 (loop for aw = (gtk4:application-active-window app)
       until (null aw)
       do (gtk4:window-close aw))
```

Comment: This looks good, unfortunately I have little experience with gtk to comment further